# Expression Typed Incorrectly or Expression too Complicated?

Tags: sql, ms-access, boolean, bit

Trying to run a rather simple query to fill a report in MS Access but its kicking back this error. It is supposed to select all records where MRC is TRUE between these 2 dates.

It works just fine when dbo_Project_Master.MRC IS NOT NULL but trying to assign any value to it causes the error. MRC is a bit type so I thought I'd be able to assign '1' to it and use that since SQL doesn't recognize boolean types.

```
SELECT 
dbo_Project_Master.ProjectID, dbo_Project_Master.Project_Name, dbo_Project_Master.Permit_Num, dbo_Municipality.Municipality, dbo_Project_Master.MRC, dbo_Project_Master.Date_Received
FROM 
(dbo_Project_Master INNER JOIN dbo_Project_Municipality ON dbo_Project_Master.ProjectID = dbo_Project_Municipality.ProjectID) INNER JOIN dbo_Municipality ON dbo_Project_Municipality.MunicipalityID = dbo_Municipality.MunicipalityID
WHERE 
(dbo_Project_Master.Date_Received >= Forms!frmCriteriaAnnualRpt!txtStartDate) AND (dbo_Project_Master.Date_Received <= Forms!frmCriteriaAnnualRpt!txtEndDate) AND (dbo_Project_Master.MRC = '1');
```

Comment: I hate myself. Thank you.

Comment: Note that Access SQL recognizes booleans just fine. It's SQL server that has no boolean type. But if it's not a passthrough query, Access should handle the translation, so you should be able to do `AND dbo_Project_Master.MRC` instead of `dbo_Project_Master.MRC = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'1'` <> `1`. With the single quotes it is a text. Without the single quotes it is a number, or here a bit.

Write `dbo_Project_Master.MRC = 1` (without the quotes). Or even better `dbo_Project_Master.MRC <> 0` because Access `True` is translated to `-1`. So `<> 0` catches both `1` and `-1`.

And btw., here = is not an assignment but a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments. Removing the quote marks fixed it.

Comment: Which comments are your referring to? Are they still there?